# Код работает неверно

Tags: jquery

```
var pic = new Image();    // создаем объект "изображение"
   pic.src = popHREF ; // указываем источник изображения(в переменной popHREF хранится URL изображения)
   $(pic).load(function() { // вешаем на наш объект анонимную функцию на событие LOAD при помощи jQuery
     $("body").append("<div id='popwin' class='popup_block'></div>");
     $('#popwin').append(pic);      
    });

   //выравнивание окна по центу
   var popWidth = ($('#popwin').width())/2;
   var popHeight = ($('#popwin').height())/2;
   alert('Ширина = '+popWidth+" Высота = "+popHeight);
```

Так вот, по идее, в функции (где load) создается изображение, и когда оно полностью загрузится, начинает работать следующий за этим код. Но в alert'e показывается, что ширина и высота равны нулю.

Есть ли другие способы дождаться полной загрузки изображения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

дело в том что аппенд происходит не сразу, а только после загрузки, а вы сразу пытаетесь выполнить код.

```
var pic = new Image();    // создаем объект "изображение"
   pic.src = popHREF ; // указываем источник изображения(в переменной popHREF хранится URL изображения)
   $(pic).load(function() { // вешаем на наш объект анонимную функцию на событие LOAD при помощи jQuery
     $("body").append("<div id='popwin' class='popup_block'></div>");
     $('#popwin').append(pic);      
    //выравнивание окна по центу
    var popWidth = ($('#popwin').width())/2;
    var popHeight = ($('#popwin').height())/2;
    alert('Ширина = '+popWidth+" Высота = "+popHeight);
    });
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. А я думал, что код, идущий после функции load(а не В ней) выполнится после окончания загрузки изображения.

Comment: load - это всего лишь событые, и когда оно выполнится не зависит от его местоположения в коде